# Opposite terminology of relaxation

Tags: terminology

Removing a condition is a relaxation of a statement. What is the opposite? (i.e. adding a condition to a statement)

Comment: Maybe "strengthening"?

Comment: @lulu I would really like to convey the feeling of "limiting the set of possible values by adding a condition", 'strengthening' feels a bit off.  I could just write it in plain text, but I was curious to see if there was any established expression.

Comment: I've seen "tightening" as well.  But I think all these are fairly informal terms.

Comment: Maybe "restricting"?

Comment: @M47145 Ah, works great! Thanks!

Comment: I.e "Restricting ourselves to the set of even primes, we need only check n=2.